# How many parameters can be sent in a single Volley POST StringRequest?

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

Many of us use Volley for sending request to save some data in MySql database. The problem is, I am currently in a situation where I need to send large number of parameters say 100 or may be even more in a single Volley request.

I haven't faced any problems yet, but just wondering what is the limit for number of parameters. I haven't found anything related to this in other asked questions.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit, however, I would question the need to send that many parameters in the first place.  Why not just one parameter, which is a JSON string, and let the backend parse the JSON for the data values?  You can use the Volley JsonObjectRequest method to do that.

Comment: well, i'm using php rest-api for parsing the JSON, and advanced JSON is still beyond me. and the data that i want to send are random (or dynamic). So, a bit confused what to do.

Comment: Then, suggest me how to parse the JsonObject in the API

Comment: I'm not familiar with the php rest-api for parsing JSON, however with API's written in C#, you can map a JSON string to a C# class object and then just use the class instance member variables however you need to.  But it sounds like you have bigger challenges if your environment is so dynamic.  You'll need to spell that out for us explicitly if you expect us to help you find a solution.

Comment: JsonObject name=new JsonObject()
name.put("key1","value1");
name.put("key2","value2");

you can add as many as you want, and pass this name(JsonObject) in your json request function.